# C# - Serializing to XML information as to which function to bind a delegate too

Tags: c#, xml, delegates, xml-serialization, eventhandler

I need to be able to save a delegate with the information of which function it is connected to. Something like this:

In C#:

```
public class Skill
{
    [XmlAttribute("SkillFunction")]
    public EventHandler<SkillEventArgs>? SkillFunction { get; set; }
}

public static void CriticalStrike(object? sender, SkillEventArgs? e)
{
}
```

So that, when I save the skill that has its `SkillFunction` set to be bound to `CriticalStrike`, it should save like this:

```
<Skills xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org         /2001/XMLSchema">
 <Skill SkillFunction="CriticalStrike" />
```

And when I deserialize it, the `SkillFunction` should be subscribed to `CriticalStrike`.

However, this does not work. Is there a workaround to do this? Or is my only option available to save the function name in a string and then hard code in a switch-case that goes through all 100 possible function names and hooks them up to the correct function? I would like to avoid any hard coding, but I don't have any idea on how I would go on about doing that.

I tried just serializing an EventHandler, but it did not work. I was expecting it to be able to save which function a delegate is bound/subscribed to.

Comment: _"Or is my only option available ..."_ - This is not serializable as is, you are correct. BUT: The alternative you have in mind is _not_ the **only** one. Part one is still valid: serialize a name or identifier for the desired action / handler whatever. But you don't have to iterate a list if you use a lookup. Maybe a Dictionary? That would then be O(1). And you could create it once at startup using reflection (=> not hardcoded).

Comment: A common sense tels it is impossible just bind  string as a function. You can look at reflections.

Comment: You need to register the event with '+='.  The skill class needs a constructor and register the event in the constructor.

Comment: Wouldnt having it in a dictionary also be considered to be "hard coded"? Also i think switch-case is faster than dictionary (atleast according to intmaker.com/dotnet-dictionary-vs-switch/ ) 

What i mean is that i would like to avoid making a full list of all the functions and pairing them with the correct name/key. WIth a dictionary i still have to do that. I would like C# to know that "CriticalStrike" is a function in my code without me explicitly linking it up. Its just a name, right?

Comment: If it needs to be dynamic the dictionary approach is the most straight forward. If the set of functions is somewhat limited You can also write a 'slow' reflection function that uses the name or a string with the class name and function name to find the right function in a specific set of classes. Then create a dictionary that sits in front of this and caches all these results to make it fast. Beware of multi threading an concurrency issues.